# Adding attribute list to collection in form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm aiming to have a drop down box in a form that will give the user a list of all the 'specialties' already available.

I have a guidelines model and this model has an attribute :specialty but I'm not sure how to add this in my form in views/guidelines/_form.html.erb (I'm using simple_form)

**guidelines_controller.rb**

*def listspecialty*

```
@speclist = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
```

*def topicspecialty*

```
 @guidelines = Guideline.find_all_by_specialty(params[:specialty])
```

**views/guidelines**

*new.html.erb*

```
<%= render 'form', speclist: @speclist %>
```

*_form.html.erb*

```
<%= f.input :specialty, as: :select, collection: speclist %>
```

*listspecialty.html.erb*

```
    <% @speclist.each do |specialty| %>
<%= link_to specialty, :action => :topicspecialty, :specialty => specialty %>
```

**ROUTES**

```
get "guidelines/listspecialty"
  get "guidelines/topicspecialty"
  match "specialty", to: "guidelines#listspecialty", as: :specialty
  get '/:id', to: 'guidelines#topic'
  get '/:id', to: 'guidelines#topicspecialty'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `simple_form` try this:

```
<%= f.input :specialty, as: :select, collection: @list %>
```

Also you could simplify your array code to:

```
@list = @guidelines.map(&:specialty).uniq
```

Or if you're getting the guidelines just for the `@list` then do:

```
@list = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
```

To pass `@list` to your form you might have to pass it to the partial:

```
# guidelines controller
def list_specialty
  #some code
  @list = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
end

# routes, something like:
match "specialty", to: "guidelines#list_specialty", as: :specialty

# where you add your partial
<%= render 'form', list: @list %>

# then in your form
<%= f.input :specialty, as: :select, collection: list %>
```

#### Update

`new.html.erb` correlates to the `guidelines#new` action, so any code you want to use in the view should also be in the action, e.g:

```
# guidelines controller
def new
  @specialties = Guideline.order(:specialty).uniq.pluck(:specialty)
  @guideline = Guideline.new
end

# in guidelines/new.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @guideline do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :some_attr %>
  <%= f.input :specialty, as: :select, collection: @specialties %>
  ....
<% end %>
```

Comment: Ha!  Thanks for the shortcut - it took me about 5 days to get my array code to work.

Comment: The f.input suggestion isn't working though - Projects/guidelines/app/views/guidelines/_form.html.erb:19: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
...t_buffer.append= ( f.input, as: :select, collection: @list )

Comment: I forgot the to add `:specialty` after `f.input`

Comment: how does it know where to get @list from (i.e. how do I reference the listspecialty action in the guidelines_controller.rb?

Comment: Thanks agaib - it's only giving me two options (yes and no) in the dropdown box on the form so it's not picking up the specialties correctly for some reason

Comment: That's weird, I have the same code in my app and it works. Do you actually have any specialties in the database?

Comment: Yes I do have specialties in the app.  Something isn't quite right - when I view a list of the specialties in a listspecialty.html.erb view  using <% @list.each do |specialty| %><%= link_to specialty, :action => :topicspecialty, :specialty => specialty %> it produces a weird result for the first one which just says /guidelines/topicspecialty and then lists the other specialties below it.  I don't know why it is showing this as the first option, but the others are there so it does have specialties in the database

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24698/discussion-between-mind-blank-and-tessad)

Comment: Ignore my last comments - but I do have specialties in the db but it is only listing yes and no as drop-down options